# exporting 3D array to Excel workbook

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, multidimensional-array

I have a 3D array (TAU) with the shape (t,l,b)=(122,40,30) that I want to export to an Excel workbook as 2D with the third dimension being the number of sheets.  So basically the result would be 30 sheets, each with a table of 122 rows and 40 columns. It takes three `for` loops (t,l and b) to form this array and at the end I take the final result and try to export it into an Excel workbook.
I am new to Python and it seems i have a problem with the syntax.  I am using pandas. 
Here is the part of the code that seems to be causing an error. Please note that TAU was created as

```
TAU=np.zeros(len(t),40,30)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter((stn + '_AOD.xlsx'), engine='xlsxwriter')
Time = pd.DataFrame(t)

for i in range(0, 40):
    TAU = pd.DataFrame(nc.variables['TAU'][:,i,:])
    Time.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=['DateTime'], sheet_name='bin%d' % i)
    TAU.to_excel(writer, index=False,header=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30], sheet_name='bin%d' % i, startcol=1)

 writer.save()

 np.close()
```

> error:
>       TAU = pd.DataFrame(nc.variables['TAU'][:,i,:])
>
> KeyError: 'TAU'

```
Exception ignored in: <bound method Workbook.__del__ of
<xlsxwriter.workbook.Workbook object at 0x0000000007D3EFD0>> Traceback
(most recent call last):   File
"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py",
line 149, in __del__ Exception: Exception caught in workbook
destructor. Explicit close() may be required for workbook.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below produces the output I think you are looking for.

```
data = np.zeros((122, 40, 30))

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

for i in range(0, 30):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data[:,:,i])
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='bin%d' % i)

writer.save()
```

Comment: Yes that helped!!  I also had to convert the time = num2date(dateti, units='days since 0001-01-01 00:00:00.0', calendar='gregorian')  ///to read it into the first column.  Thanks for your tip it helped!